# How to combine 2 icons/images in one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, playback

I've this code:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('video_background').play()"><i class="icon icon-play"></i></a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('video_background').pause()"><i class="icon icon-pause"></i></a></li>
```

That create those 2 icons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KILVu.jpg
Each icon runs a diferente function.

How can I combine the two icons, to just have 1 icon with the icon-pause visible, and onclick would change the icon to icon-play and still doing the function "document.getElementById('video_background').pause()"

Best regards

Comment: Thing which you are looking for is called CSS Sprite. Search on it and you can get many articles :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep them as a single image and only display one icon (i.e., half the image) at once, you can make a spritesheet. [This article](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) explains how to make them in detail. You simply adjust the `background-position` depending on what icon you want to be visible! Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: By using CSS sprites, you will also will eliminate one HTTP request :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some css/js, that might get you closer. http://jsfiddle.net/brocklob/6s58y/2/
If this doesn't help try rewording your question/pasting the full example.

```
<style>
.icon {
display: block;
width: 46px;
height: 46px;
background: url('http://i.imgur.com/L08OI7V.jpg') no-repeat;
background-position: right top;
}

.icon-play {
background-position: left top;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.icon').on('click', function(e) {
      $('.icon').toggleClass("icon-play");
      e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>

<button class="icon"></button>
```